# react native : What is the way to fill in the table according to "Conteiners_Count" and also "Containers_Description"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In my example I tried to fill the contents of the table with the data `Conteiners_Count` and also `Containers_Description` according to `Sampling_Request_ID` but it does not display the data.
I would be happy to help..

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRoute, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Table, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';
import { getExecutionDetail } from '../webservice_functions/tblSamplingExecution_Table';

const SikumHamechalim = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const route = useRoute();
  const params = route.params;
  const { selectedItems } = params;
  const [sikumVisible, setSikumVisible] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const sikum = await getExecutionDetail(selectedItems[0].Sampling_Request_ID);
        const typesikum = sikum;
        console.log('frog', typesikum);
        setSikumVisible(typesikum);
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn('Error with getting sikum:', err);
      }
    })();
  }, []);


  const [tableHead, setTableHead] = useState(['Container type', 'Number of containers']);
  let flatTable = {}
  sikumVisible.forEach(e =>
    flatTable[e.Containers_Description] = flatTable[e.Containers_Description] ? flatTable[e.Containers_Description] + e.Conteiners_Count :
      e.Conteiners_Count)

  const table = Object.keys(flatTable).map(key => [key, flatTable[key]])
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(table);
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.Secondary_title}>
        <Text style={styles.secondaryTitleText}>
          Concentration of containers for selected references
    </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.DividerLine}></View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff' }}>
          <Row data={tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text} />
          <Rows data={tableData} textStyle={styles.dataText} />
        </Table>
      </View>
    </>
  )
};
```

**This is the data of "typesikum" :**

```
[ {
      "Containers_Count":1,
      "Containers_Description":"DOG",
   },
   {
      "Containers_Count":2,
      "Containers_Description":"HORSE",
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

in react way you must consider that table first render would be empty until data comes from api, so change your code like this:

```
     const [tableHead, setTableHead] = useState(['Container type', 'Number of containers']);
     const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
        
        const arrangeData = ()=>{
            let rows = [];
            sikumVisible.forEach(e =>
            {
            let row = [e.Containers_Description,e.Conteiners_Count];
            rows.push(row);
            });
            setTableData(rows);
        }
        useEffect(()=>{arrangeData ();},[sikumVisible]);
          useEffect(() => {
            (async () => {
              try {
                const sikum = await getExecutionDetail(selectedItems[0].Sampling_Request_ID);
                const typesikum = sikum;
                console.log('frog', typesikum);
                setSikumVisible(typesikum);
              } catch (err) {
                console.warn('Error with getting sikum:', err);
              }
            })();
          }, []);
```

in above code after "sikumVisible" changes by api call, second effect arrange data and fill out table, also you can arrange data after api call and pass data to be arrange and set to table

Comment: its not work ..
the problem i think is in the way of the forEach function and also the the map function..

Comment: its gives an error : undefined is not a function (near '...data.map...')

Comment: i changed arrange code, it seems in document of library it want array of arrays for row

Comment: i fixed it, but this code is just a hint buddy

Comment: now it not show the Conteiners_Count in the table .. it display only the Containers_Description